# Sum columns with a less or equal than criteria and name criteria in Excel

Tags: c#, excel, pivot-table, vba

I have a pivottable in Excel worksheet1 which goes like this:
The rowlabels are 'codename' and '#rulenumber'.

```
RowLabels                       Value
 Codename1                    2315(total)
  5                           5
  10                          249
  25                          60
  40                          0
  50                          10
  60                          1991
Codename2                    (total)
  5                           xx
  10                          xx
  25                          xx
  40                          xx
  50                          xx
  ...                         xx
```

I have another table in worksheet2 that needs to pull the sum of a determined set of rules from a codename. So, if my set of rules are those less or equal than 50, then I will get the following results:

For codename1, I will get 324 and for codename2 an xx value.

How can I do this? I tried will a getpivotdata function but it doesnt work because as far as I know, it gets values visible in the pivottable.

I can use macros or even use a language like c# to solve this.

Comment: You should be able to add a filter on the pivot table itself.

Comment: Won't work, because I don't want to filter the pivot table. I need to pull the data from the pivot table and order in in another table in another worksheet                                                                                                         
    Name                    Rule 50
      Codename1          344
      Codename2              xx`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

Tabular layout for PT
`Repeat item labels` checked in Field Settings
`Row Labels` is in Column E (so `Codenames` in ColumnF)
`Values`is in G
I2:I... contains a list of `Codenames`

then in J2 and copied down to suit:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((E:E=I2)*(F:F<=50),(G:G))
```